# Passing value using Ajax to my PHP

Tags: laravel-4

My ajax code didn't work, i am trying to pass the colorit value from my script to my controller(php), but the ajax didnt work. the alert box with out put 'success!' didn't pop out and also the alert(colorit). but if i comment the ajax code, the alert(colorit) pops. is there any wrong in my ajax code? please help. tnx. sorry im new to this.

script

```
$( ".colorselector_1" ).change(function() {
       var colorit = document.getElementById("colorselector_1").value;
       alert(colorit);
       $.ajax({    
            url: '/addItemColor',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'colorit':colorit},
            success:function(data){
                alert('success!');
            }                      
        });             
});
```

html

```
 <select id="colorselector_1" class="colorselector_1">
 <option value="#A0522D" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option>
 <option value="#CD5C5C" data-color="#CD5C5C" selected="selected">indianred</option>
 </select>
```

route

```
Route::get('addItemColor','CakeController@addItemColor');
```

controller

```
 public function addItemColor(){
 .......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I just suggest something?

First of all, this is why you have vars like "error" in place. So the first thing you should do is change your code accordingly:

```
$( ".colorselector_1" ).change(function() {
    var colorit = document.getElementById("colorselector_1").value;
    alert(colorit);
    $.ajax({    
        url: '/addItemColor',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'colorit':colorit,
        success:function(data){
            alert('success!')},
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        alert('error');        
        }                      
    });
});
```

Another thing to remember is that you have the Network panel in developer tools where you can see all of the calls that were made and whether they had successful responses or not, such as in Chrome when you go to More tools -> Developer tools. These two will help you find the answer of "whether there is something" for yourself, like if there's a wrong URL or something.

[image: Network panel of dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you point to the right `url` in your `$.ajax` function.

Comment: tnx for the rply. i tried url: 'addItemColor', but it didnt work. any suggestion?